# PC sending continuous ARP broadcast requests

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark

Have started to toy around with WireShark and noticed that one of the PCs connected to my network is continuously sending an ARP request to every IP within the network.

To clarify:

- Device IP is 192.168.1.11

  - Who has 192.168.1.1. Tell 192.168.1.11
  - Who has 192.168.1.2. Tell 192.168.1.11
  - ...
  - ...
  - Who has 192.168.1.255. Tell 192.168.1.11

And repeat.

Any reason for this? I have another 6 or so devices on network but none of them do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate an active network scanner on 192.168.1.11, as it seems to be going through the whole `192.168.1.0/24` subnet, looking for online hosts.